# Убрать web/app.php из урла

Tags: .htaccess, php, symfony2

Все запросы проходят через файл web/app.php (аналогично index.php), например, запрос на главную страничку  - http://adwords-up.com/web/app.php, вход - http://adwords-up.com/web/app.php/login. Я хочу часть web/app.php убрать из ссылки. В конфигурации .htaccess по умолчанию перенаправлять на web/app.php, чтоб запрос на главную, например, имел вид - http://adwords-up.com/, а страничка входа - http://adwords-up.com/login.

Вот так выглядит /etc/apache2/sites-available/adwords-up.conf:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t$
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
ServerName adwords-up

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/adwords-up/web
# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) web/app.php/$1 [L]
```

возможно так.

Comment: К сожалению, не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Сам хост надо к web создавать. В web .htaccess должен содержать следующее:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

И убедитесь на 100%, что mod_rewrite установлен и корректно работает.